# How to generate mission test scenarios

Tags: python, testing, server

I'm working on a software that deals with drones.
My team introduced a server to allow command and control activities with multiple drones.
Now, I'd like to test its API and create a python module for automated testing. 
The API includes actions like add marker, delete marker and so on and so forth that you can do in the app.
I've been researching if there might be a tool to allow me to randomize these actions automatically to create scenarios that imitate user actions.
For example:
check the license, add mission, add a marker, fly to position and delete Marker.

Each of those actions is a request sent to the server within the app, but I've already recreated those activities as functions in python. The server actions have also been written in Python(server is tornado). Now I just need to find a way to randomize their activation(the data they send to the server is generated randomly and legally as well, and that's not a problem).

So before wasting a lot of my time creating these scenarios by hand, I'm sure someone already faced this kind of problem. I couldn't find it here though. Searched for hours but there are so many questions I might have missed something related to my issue.
I can build such a tool myself and even share a git to it here if it comes to that. Then it will be helpful to anyone encountering this question.
I thought it would be worth asking anyway.

Let me know if there are any other details you need to know to answer this question.
Thanks!

Comment: So if I got you right, you have a way to pass the commands, but need a way to automatically *generate* the list of commands to make usable scenarios?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Ideally, sometime in the future, we will build the entire Cartesian product of available actions to test the server.

Comment: Building a Cartesian product or mission orders would actually be one of the easiest ways to implement programmatically, but I presume  it would be a very inefficient way of testing, as it would include scenarios like "add marker", "delete marker", "add marker","delete marker" x10.